# Echo a variable that many times

Tags: bash

I want a sequence of numbers where the number occurs as many times as it's value. e.g.:

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

The number do not necessarily need to occur in any order. Each just needs to appear the appropriate amount of times.

I tried using a `for` loop in various ways to achieve this, but none had the required output

```
for i in {1..400}; do
    for i in {1..$i}; do
        echo $i;
    done;
done
```

and

```
for i in `seq 1 400`; do
    for i in `seq 1 $i`; do
        echo $i;
    done;
done
```

The first outputs:

```
{1..1}
{1..2}
{1..3}
{1..4}
{1..5}
{1..6}
{1..7}
{1..8}
{1..9}
{1..10}
```

and the second outputs the opposite of what I need. The number 1 occurs 400 times, and the number 400 occurs one time. In an attempt to counter this, I went through the script flipping the order of the sequence.

```
for i in `seq 400 1`; do
    for i in `seq 1 $i`; do
```

then

```
for i in `seq 1 400`; do
    for i in `seq $i 1`; do
```

then

```
for i in `seq 400 1`; do
    for i in `seq $i 1`; do
```

and none of them produced the required output.

How can I output 1 one time, 2 two times, 3 three times... until 400?

Comment: The `{1..10}` notation only works if the numbers are both literals, not if either is the result of evaluating an expression.  See [Brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) for the specification of `{1..10}` notation (and note that brace expansion occurs before variables are expanded, which is why you run into the problem), and [Bash Pitfall 33](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D) for an explanation (albeit moderately terse).

Answer (score 2):

You were almost right, you just got your loop variables confused because you called them both `i`:

```
for i in `seq 1 400`; do
    for j in `seq 1 $i`; do
        echo $i;
    done;
done
```

Note how the second loop variable is now called `j`, to avoid [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the outer loop variable that you want to print.

---

As a side note, as sputnick points out, this style is somewhat antiquated. In contemporary bash, you could instead write

```
for ((i=1; i<=400; i++))
do
  for ((j=0; j<i; j++))
  do
    printf "%s\n" "$i"
  done
done
```

The logic is the same, but it's significantly faster because it doesn't fork external commands, and doesn't require linux-specific utilities like `seq`.

Comment: Why using backquotes in 2014 ? The backquote ` is used in the old-style command substitution.

Check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Your first sentence is not the major problem, but a correct solution.

Comment: That the brace expansion `{1..$i}` does not happen, even if it was the right variable. Jonathan's comment on the question explains it.

Comment: @glennjackman You shouldn't have stopped reading there. The solution here is literally a 1 character change from the second code sample.